# XAML:Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

**I am building a Custom Modal Box in wpf Something like this**
[image: ModalBOX Example]

I want users to Add `Modal Children Control element` from XAML using some Custom Modal Element.
Since we cannot create a Child Window inside Main Window.
So I am doing it indirectly using xaml and c#.

**Here is my sample code Implementing Modal**

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<local:ModalWindow>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="400" Height="400">
            <Button Width="110"></Button>
        </Border>
</local:ModalWindow>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
class ModalWindow : StackPanel
{

    public ModalWindow() 
    {

        StackPanel myGrid = this;
        this.Height = 400;
        this.Width = 400; 
        Window myWindow = new MyWindow(this);

    }

 class MyWindow : Window
{

    public MyWindow(object x) : base()
    {
       this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        this.AllowsTransparency = true;
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        this.Opacity = 0.7;
        this.Background = Brushes.Black;
        this.AddChild(x);
        this.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

**On loading it displays with an RunTimeError**

```
 Error: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first"
```

**Is there any way to disconnecting this node from MainWindow first and then add this Exact node to my New Window as its child.**

Please Help!

Comment: You can't add same element in different Visual tree. Either you need to remove element first from previous Visual Tree OR add new instance of control.

Comment: You should really use MVVM and the Command pattern for this. WPF was built to support it. Doing it "your way" means you will have to fight your technology all along the way.